# StackExchange Polygon using C#

Tags: c#, stackexchange.redis

is there any StackExchange quicker way to validate if the point is in the Polygon using Redis.

I have a Latitude and Longitude point and want to know in which city it falls. I have the polygon data for the cities.

Currently I am using this code and it works, but i find it too inefficient and not scaleable when i have to check among hundreds of City Polygons.
Would like to use Redis to do this.

Please assist.

```
    City1.Add(new GeoPoints(5.9581, 1.11865));
    City1.Add(new GeoPoints(4.99572, -1.47411));
    City1.Add(new GeoPoints(6.19298, -2.00145));
    City1.Add(new GeoPoints(6.98422, 0.38257));
    City1.Add(new GeoPoints(5.9581, 1.11865));

    City2.Add(new GeoPoints(-6.4461, 39.11052));
    City2.Add(new GeoPoints(-7.19336, 39.68732));
    City2.Add(new GeoPoints(-7.23151, 38.98969));
    City2.Add(new GeoPoints(-7.00528, 38.55296));
    City2.Add(new GeoPoints(-6.4461, 39.11052));


public bool IsPointInPolygon(List<GeoPoints> poly, GeoPoints point)
{
    int i, j;
    bool c = false;
    for (i = 0, j = poly.Count - 1; i < poly.Count; j = i++)
    {
        if ((((poly[i].Lt <= point.Lt) && (point.Lt < poly[j].Lt))
                || ((poly[j].Lt <= point.Lt) && (point.Lt < poly[i].Lt)))
                && (point.Lg < (poly[j].Lg - poly[i].Lg) * (point.Lt - poly[i].Lt)
                    / (poly[j].Lt - poly[i].Lt) + poly[i].Lg))

            c = !c;
    }
    return c;
}
```

Comment: Use the dot product to find the distance of the point to each edge. If all have the same sign, and the shape is closed and convex, the point is inside the polygon.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is not currently any geo API in redis that supports polygon queries; [this is the closest](https://redis.io/commands/geosearch), and it doesn't come near. So: I don't think you can use vanilla redis for this.

There may be a "module" that adds such usage; if so, SE.Redis allows modules to be invoked via Execute.